# How to get Formview control by javascript's getElementByID?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, formview

```
function ValidateYesNoOption(strIdToCheck, strIdToEnable) {
    var elementID = document.getElementById('<%=frmvwRiccAssess.FindControl("rblMeetingPlace").ClientID %>');
}
```

How do I write frmView.FindControl(strIdToCheck).clientID instead of what I have up there now?